# Push Notification Android IntelXDK

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Version Deprecated pushPlugin the building in intel XDK was good, and next version phonegap-plugin-push, not building my application more.
Please, this version not build intel xdk, this is error.

compileReleaseJava.../pushApp/platforms/android/src/com/adobe/phonegap/push/PushInstanceIDListenerService.java:7: error: package com.google.android.gms.iid does not exist
import com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID;

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your problem is here, but InstanceID is a class from Google Play Services are you including this on your project?

Answer (score 0):

Hello add this push plugin works well for Intel XDK Cordova CLI v 4.0+ builds

https://github.com/Whebcraft/CordovaPush

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution: If you are using CLI 4.1.2, add that plugin from a Git repo using the following parameters:

https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin
git ref tag: 2.4.0
The CLI 4.1.2 works for all apps.

For CLI 5.1.1, add that plugin from the Cordova registry using the following parameters:

phonegap-plugin-push
version: 1.2.3